# Rails - Is it terrible to call models directly in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

So I have a search partial that I want to be able to use anywhere in the site. I realize that it's generally bad to put logic in the view, but can I do something like

```
= form_for User.search do |f|
```

Or is it an absolute semantic must that I put any kind of model-method call in the controller, even if I'm not modifying anything?

Comment: Anything in the view can be manipulated by the user especially if they're smart users. I would put my code in the controller then call it through the view.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little bit, I'm almost 100% sure that if I put logic in the view, it cannot be manipulated by the user.

Comment: Say for example you put the search form logic in the view a user can hack your form via SQL Injection etc. Never underestimate your users. Try using a helper method rather then putting your raw code into the view.

Comment: @coletrain: I'm not sure where you're getting this from, but a user cannot simply 'hack' a view form unless you build it carelessly - the view is contained and read on the server _only_.  Making a model call in a view may not be a very clean approach, but that will not make it prone to any sort of vulnerability per se.

Comment: @bwheeler96: The only downside I can see is that it makes integration testing and maintenance a bit more difficult.  If you're willing to forgo these issues, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: @PinnyM, elaborate and write this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use the presenter pattern my friend!

There's a great railscast about the Draper gem [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper)

Hope that will steer you away from the potentially painful path you tread!